# Library function needs a std::function<void(void)>, how do I pass in a class function?

Tags: c++

I am creating a C++ class for an embedded application, and a library I am using defines some functions that expect a function parameter to set up a callback:

```
class WebServer
{
public:
    typedef std::function<void(void)> THandlerFunction;
    void on(const String &uri, THandlerFunction handler);
}
```

I am using this class in mine:

```
MyWebControl::MyWebControl()
{
    WebServer _server(80);
}

MyWebControl::onHandler()
{
    // do stuff
}
```

And now I need to "wire up" my `onHandler` function using the `_server` object's `on()` function:

```
MyWebControl::MyWebControl()
{
    WebServer _server(80);
    _server.on("/", onHandler);
}
```

But that gives me a compiler error:

> error: invalid use of non-static member function _server.on("/", onHandler);

I can make this method static in this case, but is that necessary?

Comment: It should be static if it can be. Better yet, use a free function

Comment: @AluanHaddad Mmmm nope.

Comment: I said if it can be. Obviously if it doesn't depend on instance state, why make it a method?

Comment: Did you manage to use the `_server` instance inside the `onHandler()` function? I want to send response to the client using the `_server.send(...)` but it's crashing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It needs you to pass a pointer to the `MyWebControl` on which the callback will be invoked. Fortunately, this is easy!

This is what [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) is for:

```
_server.on("/", std::bind(&MyWebControl::onHandler, this));
```

Or a lambda:

```
_server.on("/", [this]() { this->onHandler(); });
// (the `this` isn't even needed!)
```

Both will work with your `std::function` nicely.

Comment: The lambda version should be `_server.on("/", [this]() { this->onHandler(); });`, otherwise all local variables will be captured by value - in OP's example this means creating a copy of `_server`.

Comment: @joe_chip They won't and it doesn't, because `_server` is not referenced inside the lambda ... but specifically capturing only `this` is probably better anyway. Capturing `=` when I only need `this` is a [perhaps bad] habit of mine.

Comment: @joe_chip Compare [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8baf43919fc6ab48) with [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0dc1784f32be13ea). Captures only take place if needed.